# Django admin prepopulated fields and fieldsets

Tags: django, django-admin

I am using Django 3.2

I have the following model:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    slug = models.SlugField()
    # remaining fields listed below
```

In Admin manager, I have the model:

```
class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        ('General', {
            'fields': [
                        'title',
                        'description',
                        'information',
                        'cover_photo',
                        'gallery', 
            ]

        }),
        ('Details', {
            'fields' : [
            'is_cancelled',
            'start',
            'finish',
            'video_url',
            ]

        }),
    ]
    
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title',), }


admin.site.register(Foo, FooAdmin)
```

When I attempt to create a new Foo in the admin manager, I get the error:

> KeyError: "Key 'slug' not found in 'FooForm'. Choices are: cover_photo, description, finish, gallery, information, is_cancelled, start, title, video_url."

When I add the slug field to the list of fieldsets, it works, but then the slug field is shown on the form (which I don't want).

I know that I can solve this by overriding `Foo.save()`, but I want the admin manager to handle this for me.

So, how do I use fieldsets with prepopulated fields that are not supposed to appear on the form?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot exclude slug from admin fields since you are including it in prepopulated_fields. However, you can override your model's save method like below to generate a **unique** slug. You can make general BaseModel with this save method and extend your models with slug fields everytime:

```
from django.utils.text import slugify


def generate_unique_slug(klass, field):
    """
    return unique slug if origin slug is exist.
    eg: `foo-bar` => `foo-bar-1`

    :param `klass` is Class model.
    :param `field` is specific field for title.
    """
    origin_slug = slugify(field)
    unique_slug = origin_slug
    numb = 1
    while klass.objects.filter(slug=unique_slug).exists():
        unique_slug = "%s-%d" % (origin_slug, numb)
        numb += 1
    return unique_slug


class BaseModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstact = True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if hasattr(self, "slug") and hasattr(self, "title"):
            if self.slug:
                if slugify(self.title) != self.slug:
                    self.slug = generate_unique_slug(self.__class__, self.title)
            else:  # create
                self.slug = generate_unique_slug(self.__class__, self.title)

        super().save(*args, **kwargs)


class Foo(BaseModel):
    title = models.CharField()
    slug = models.SlugField()
    # remaining fields listed below


class AnotherModelWithSlug(BaseModel):
    title = models.CharField()
    slug = models.SlugField()
```

Comment: He said: "I know that I can solve this by overriding Foo.save(), but I want the admin manager to handle this for me."

Comment: okay, let him decide, which one is better, overriding forms everytime when he needs to generate slugs or just make one general model and extend his model with it.

Comment: Your solution is simpler and more effective, even I would have proceeded in your way since it is the standard solution. As you pointed out to me the fact that in my answer the slug is not unique, I pointed out to you that even though your answer is correct and better, it is not what he asked for, regardless of what he will choose his question ruled out this solution in principle. We are not having a contest, take it easy, is a simple question. We try to give the most correct answer, not to make a competition for 25 points, that is not the purpose of the forum.

Comment: Of course man) Chill)

Answer (score 0):

You can override the form of the admin:

```
from django.utils.text import slugify  


class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        ('General', {
            'fields': [
                        'title',
                        'description',
                        'information',
                        'cover_photo',
                        'gallery', 
            ]
        }),
        ('Details', {
            'fields' : [
            'is_cancelled',
            'start',
            'finish',
            'video_url',
            ]
        }),
    ]
   
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, change=False, **kwargs):
       OriginalForm = super().get_form(request, obj, change, **kwargs)

       class Form(OriginalForm):
          def save(self, commit=True):
             instance = super().save(commit=False)
             instance.slug = slugify(instance.title)  # Here
             if commit:
                instance.save()
             return instance

       return Form
```

As you said the best (and simplest) solution would be to override the `save` method of the model.